# Мультиязычность сайта

Tags: seo, поисковые-системы

На сайте находиться три языка: Русский (дефолт), Английский, Украинский. Включаются они путём нажатия на определенную ссылку, после чего пользователю записывается кука (ru, en, ua) и подключается словарь его языка.

Поисковой робот может перейти по ссылке, но записать куку не сможет. Соответственно проиндексирут только дефолтную версия. Как заставить его индексировать и другие версии?

P.s: создавать отдельные версии используя поддомены (en.site.ru) не подходит.

Comment: объясните подробнее, каким образом я могу попасть на любую страницу вашего сайта на любом языке по урлу? если никак, то как вы думаете гугл будет отдавать юзерам ссылки на все ваши страницы на разных языках?

Comment: Не знаю. К примеру, ВКонтакте - она имеет мультиязычность, но не имет версий типо en.vk.com, но по запросу в Google из США в результате отобразиться текст на английском.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как заставить его индексировать и другие версии?

Никак. Такой подход работать не будет.

Используйте один из трех предложенных вариантов:

1. Самый правильный, от которого вы открещиваетесь - это поддомены вида `en.site.com`, `ru.site.com` и `ua.site.com`. При этом на домене `site.com` могут находиться или список доступных языков, или автоматический редирект. В крайнем случае там может находится контент на языке, который был определен автоматически, но так делать, насколько я знаю, не рекомендуется.
2. Второй вариант - это засунуть язык в саму ссылку, например `site.com/en/`, `site.com/ru/` и `site.com/ua/`. В остальном всё аналогично предыдущему пункту.
3. Третий вариант - купить региональные домены: `site.ru`, `site.ua` и `site.com` (для англоязычных пользователей).

Если вы используете 1 и 2 варианты, также было бы идеально (но не обязательно), чтобы в качестве основного домена был не `.ru`, а какой-нибудь из международной зоны, например `.com`, `.org` или `.net`.

Также не забудьте настроить связь между страницами с разными языками так, чтобы поисковики смогли разобраться в них. Подробнее на эту тему:

- [Как использовать атрибут hreflang для указания языка или регионального URL](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077)
- [Мультирегиональные и многоязычные сайты](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192)

Answer (score 1):

Создайте папки для каждого из языков. В head каждой страницы примените атрибуты hreflang. Обратите внимание, что атрибут hreflang="x-default" обозначает наилучшую версию данной страницы на данном языке, т.е. это атрибут заменяет атрибут canonical. Поэтому эти атрибуты не рекомендуют совмещать на одной странице. **[Справка Гугл Как использовать атрибут hreflang для указания языка или регионального URL](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=ru)**.

Comment: Это то есть сделать три одинаковых сайта на разных языках?

Comment: Если да, то как я писал выше такой вариант не приветствуется.

Comment: Нет. Просто создайте папки для этих языков. Например: example.com/ru/ ++ example.com/en/ ++ example.com/ua/ .

Comment: Скрипты ведь будут размещаться во всех папках одинаково. К примеру, файл index.php мне нужно будет разместить в 3-х папках на разных языках. К примеру, если мне будет его необходимо изменить, то придётся вносить изменения в трёх папках.

Comment: Во-первых файл index должен быть для сайта только в одном экземпляре. Этой файл ваш сервер показывает при запросе доменного имени сайта. Для папок с языками, вероятно, надо создавать main-ru или start-ua или же что-то подобное.

Comment: Да. вам надо будет вносить изменения в трёх папках. Но вы сообщаете: "На сайте находиться три языка: Русский (дефолт), Английский, Украинский. Включаются они путём нажатия на определенную ссылку". Значит вы уже имеете файлы/страницы для этих языков и их в любом случае надо редактировать при изменениях.

Comment: @ДенисПавлик, в современной разработке на PHP принято использовать единую точку входа в приложение в виде одного единственного файла `index.php` и, соответственно, роутинг. Используйте фреймворки, а не самопальные решения, и подобные вопросы и проблемы решатся сами собой.